# Need a less invasive way to host a C# MVC app in docker over https

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, https, kestrel-http-server

I have a C# asp.net mvc app. I launch it via docker and it works perfectly. It even works over https. On the initial run, I have to run these commands:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https -ep ${HOME}/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx -p <MY PASSWORD>
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Then I launch the app via `docker-compose --env-file .env up`. The `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  data:

services:
  postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg:
    image: postgres
    # explicit container name
    container_name: postgresql_vlt_bg
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql_vlt_bg
  amaranth_main:
    container_name: amaranth_main
    links:
      - postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg
    depends_on:
      - postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:5000
      - 8001:5001
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Release
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=${Kestrel_Cert_Password}
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=${Kestrel_Cert_Rel_Path}
      - ApiEndpoints__MainNet__2=${API_KEY_BLOCKCHAIN}
      - ApiEndpoints__TestNet__2=${API_KEY_BLOCKCHAIN}
      - ConnectionStrings__db=${CONNECTION_STRING_DB}
      - ApiEndpoints__EmailUsername=${EMAIL_USERNAME}
      - ApiEndpoints__EmailPassword=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
      - ApiEndpoints__SmtpDomain=${SMPT_DOMAIN}
      - ApiEndpoints__SmtpPort=${SMPT_PORT}
      - ApiEndpoints__SmtpPostmarkKey=${SMPT_POSTMARK_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ${Kestrel_Cert_Abs_Path}:/https:ro
```

My `${Kestrel_Cert_Abs_Path}` is set to `~/.aspnet/https` and my `${Kestrel_Cert_Rel_Path}` is set to `/https/aspnetapp.pfx`

The problem is that a fellow developer with whom I am working didn't want to run the `dotnet dev-certs https` commands because he didn't want to mess with his local host computer's dev-certs. Is there any way to launch an asp.net mvc app over https without needing to run the `dotnet dev-certs https` commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your certificates in "amaranth_main" container

Something like:

```
docker-compose exec amaranth_main sh -c "dotnet dev-certs https --clean"
docker-compose exec amaranth_main sh -c "dotnet dev-certs https -ep /https/aspnetapp.pfx -p <MY PASSWORD>"
docker-compose exec amaranth_main sh -c "dotnet dev-certs https --trust"
```

Comment: The problem here is that without the keys set the docker container fails to build.  `amaranth_main               | Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:<SOME RANDOM NUMBER>:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file`  

So I can't get the container running in the first place to run your `docker-compose exec` commands.

Comment: then run it dockerfile
`RUN dotnet dev-certs https --clean && dotnet dev-certs https -ep /https/aspnetapp.pfx -p <MY PASSWORD> && dotnet dev-certs https --trust`